# IText sharp PDF Writer not display HTML correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am generating PDF with ITextSharp, I am generating HTML table in pdf document,but its not displaying correctly in PDF file. I have copied the generated HTML and checked in a HTML file, its displaying it correctly in HTML file

This is my HTML in an HTML file
[image: This is my HTML in an HTML file]

This is I am getting in PDF file 
[image]

This is my code

```
 var data = MyClass.GetHistory();//It returns a Data Table
            var stream = new MemoryStream();
            Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 50, 50, 25, 25);
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
            document.Open();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                sb.Append("<table style=\"border-collapse: collapse;  border-spacing: 0;  width: 100%;  margin-bottom: 15px;  border: 1px solid #dddddd; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px\">");
                sb.Append("<thead>");
                sb.Append("<tr>" + title + "</tr");
                sb.Append("<tr>");
                sb.Append(" <th style=\"padding: 8px;  line-height: 1.428571429;  vertical-align: top;  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;  border: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;  background:#DCEBFD; text-align:left;\">Date</th>");
                sb.Append(" <th style=\"padding: 8px;  line-height: 1.428571429;  vertical-align: top;  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;  border: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;  background:#DCEBFD; text-align:left;\">Description</th>");
                sb.Append(" <th style=\"padding: 8px;  line-height: 1.428571429;  vertical-align: top;  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;  border: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;  background:#DCEBFD; text-align:left;\">City</th>");
                sb.Append(" <th style=\"padding: 8px;  line-height: 1.428571429;  vertical-align: top;  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;  border: 1px solid #dddddd; border-bottom: 2px solid #dddddd;  background:#DCEBFD; text-align:left;\">State</th>");
                sb.Append(" </tr>");
                sb.Append(" </thead>");
                sb.Append(" <tbody>");

                foreach (var rows in data.Rows)
                {
                    sb.Append("<tr>");
                    foreach (var item in ((System.Data.DataRow)(rows)).ItemArray)
                    {
                        sb.Append("<td style=\"padding: 8px;  line-height: 1.428571429;  vertical-align: top;  border-top: 1px solid #dddddd;  border: 1px solid #dddddd; width: 125px\">" + item + "</td>");
                    }
                    sb.Append("</tr>");
                }

                //sb.Append("<td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td>");

                //sb.Append(" <tr><td>This is a test</td><td>2/td><td>3</td><td>4</td><td>5</td><tr/>");
                //sb.Append(" <tr><td>This is a test</td><td>This is a test</td><td>This is a test</td><td>This is a test</td><td>This is a test</td><tr/>");
                sb.Append(" </tbody>");
                sb.Append(" </table>");
```

Second I want to display only Year and Month from Date,How can I check inside foreach loop if the current item is a datetime?

Comment: need to see your generated html also.. from your `sb` variable

Comment: Why are you hand coding html in order to generate a PDF using itext?  Why don't you just use the itext PDFPTable class etc?

Comment: @AnantDabhi I am posting it but it will make question too big

Comment: That said, you may want to look at this: http://mikesdotnetting.com/Article/205/Exporting-The-Razor-WebGrid-To-PDF-Using-iTextSharp

Comment: ok.. nop .. but it seems you need to use `inline css`  coz its not supprt external css

Comment: I am using Inline CSS

Comment: @Paddy Let me check it :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use `iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable` object in this case. The html table seems to be a simpler one and you can accomplish your needs more faster with `iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPTable`.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, neons. This answer would be improved by including sample code for using your suggested class, as well as a link to any documentation or examples there might be.